# wp core install database connection error

Tags: installation, wp-cli

I am new to wordpress but not to programming to please bear with me. I am trying to get a new wordpress project up and running locally using the wp-cli.

But when I run the following command:

```
wp core install --url=example.com --title=WP-EXAMPLE --admin_user=******* --admin_password=****** --admin_email=******
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at `localhost`. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
```

I was able to run the `wp config` create and `wp db create` commands without issue and a database was create so I know that the database username and password are correct. Is there a step I am missing?

The output of `wp --info` is as follows:

```
OS: Darwin 17.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.6.0: Tue May  8 15:22:16 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.61.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/zsh
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php
PHP version:    7.1.16
php.ini used:
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /Users/admin/code/wp-example
WP-CLI packages dir:
WP-CLI global config:
WP-CLI project config:
WP-CLI version: 1.5.1
```

Since there are so many blank items I feel as though I am missing something although I have following all of the steps that I have found in quick start guides for setting up wordpress from the CLI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First ensure the normal browser install works. If not, here's a really good article on that: [How to Fix the Error Establishing a Database Connection in WordPress](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/).

Next thing to note is that your database may not be hosted on `localhost`. Then try to create the `wp-config.php` using `127.0.0.1` or `127.0.0.1:8889` (for MAMP for example) or something similar. On an existing installation this can be fixed by replacing the `DB_HOST` with `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');` in your `wp-config.php`.

For an existing site you could also try it with `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` in your `wp-config.php` and then access the site in a browser to let WordPress fix some common database issues for you.

The article also suggest to create a raw `testconnection.php` file in your WordPress root (replaced the database credentials with yours) and call that in a browser `http://example.com/testconnection.php` to see what will be returned:

> ```
> <?php
> $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
> if (!$link) {
>   die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
> }
> echo 'Connected successfully';
> mysqli_close($link);
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Only setting `127.0.0.1:8889` did the trick for me. Thank you